# Mac OSX Server - Apply to enclosed items function

Tags: macos, permissions

Just wondering if someone can clarify if apply to enclosed items on a folder in Mac OSX will add a permission for that particular user and not remove existing permissions or it will completely overwrite the permissions?

i.e
Level 1 folder
Admin - RW
John - RW

Level 2 Folder
John - RW

Level 3 Folder
John - RW

I want to add Admin as read write on all levels below the level one folder while keeping John's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

*First a quick note:* Since your question is about system/server configuration, it is really better suited for one of the other sites in the Stack Exchange network (Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions):

- https://superuser.com/
- https://serverfault.com/

**In any case, here is a quick answer to your question:**

Using the "Apply to enclosed items..." function will overwrite/replace all existing permissions on the files and subfolders, as applicable. In past (old) versions of OSX, this function would sometimes produce strange results, such as replacing the read/write permissions but failing to change owners/groups, but modern macos versions perform a total replacement in all ways it is applicable.

Note the warning dialog box when you run the function:
https://d.pr/i/2cRgPI

Hope that helps.